# create core php file in yii framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

i want to access core php file in yii using directly access from web url

my htaccess is

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: directly place your file in root directory where your index.php placed

Comment: but its not working i face  url not found

Comment: I have just tested and it is working. create new file test.php place where you index.php file and access url like http://yourdomain.com/test.php

Answer (score 1):

Update by adding exception for your file name

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yourfile\.php$
```

Comment: add it below # RewriteBase /